# How to add two label in one gridbox?

Tags: java, jlabel, grid-layout

How can I add two label in the same grid box? e.g. in row 1, col 1 the will be 2 labels? 
The code below will add the label in two different grid.

```
JPanel chckBox = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,8,3,3)); 

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("A");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("B");
...
chckBox.add(label1);
chckBox.add(label2);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `JPanel` into that part of the grid and have the two labels as children of that panel (which can have its own layout manager).